# TextView isn't wraping on small screen Samsung Devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, samsung-mobile, android-relativelayout

I have problem with text wrapping on small screen Samsung devices. On other phones like S4 everything is ok.

Let's look on the screens:

Correct one (HTC Desire Z):

[image: Correct one (HTC Desire Z):]

Incorrect (Samsung S4 Mini):

[image: Incorrect (Samsung S4 Mini):]

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_web"
    android:layout_marginRight="334dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="334dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Rel1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TextView
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/AppName"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/created"
        android:id="@+id/Created"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AppName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ms"
        android:id="@+id/MS"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/Created"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_page"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MS"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Could You tell me why it's rendering like that?

Comment: I suggest you start by cleaning up your inner `RelativeLayout`. You have **nine** attributes trying to set the positioning of this `RelativeLayout`, and many of them are in conflict. Then, view your activity in Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`** and see whether the positioning rules that you wind up using are giving you the correct position.

Comment: That many attributes were added when I was trying to fix this issue. Before that there were few of them.

Comment: I changed xml to before version. It's strange, because on other devices everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the `Relative Layout`. It's not a good fit for this type of layout.

Use the horizontal `LinearLayout` instead for your main container. Divide the screen into 2 parts, the `imageView` with set width and height, and another `LinearLayout` (vertical) with width set to 0dp and `layout_weight` to 1. Fill the vertical one with your 4 `TextView`s and center them. To make sure text will be visible call

```
.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
.setSingleLine(true);
.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(2);
.setSelected(true);
```

on your `TextView`s to make them scroll.

This should work on all devices with all types of screens, but you should be able to also just design special type of xml for small screens if you want to go that way.

Comment: Thank You ;) Now everything is okej.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have this attribute, and 334dp is probably wider then the entire display:

```
android:layout_marginRight="334dp"
```

Did you mean something more reasonable like "34dp"?

Comment: It's correct, because I have 
    `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
to position this image in correct place.